# Find index of min value in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I've a 2-Dim array containing the residual sum of squares of a given fit (unimportant here).

```
RSS[i,j] = np.sum((spectrum_theo - sp_exp_int) ** 2)
```

I would like to find the matrix element with the minimum value AND its position (i,j) in the matrix. Find the minimum element is OK:

```
RSS_min = RSS[RSS != 0].min()
```

but for the index, I've tried:

```
ij_min = np.where(RSS == RSS_min)
```

which gives me:

```
ij_min =  (array([3]), array([20]))
```

I would like to obtain instead:

ij_min = (3,20)

If I try :

```
ij_min = RSS.argmin()
```

I obtain:

```
ij_min = 0,
```

which is a wrong result.

Does it exist a function, in Scipy or elsewhere, that can do it? I've searched on the web, but I've found answers leading only with 1-Dim arrays, not 2- or N-Dim.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I've tried: ij_min = RSS.argmin() and I got ij_min = 0, which isn't the right thing...

Comment: `RSS.argmin()` shouldn't be giving you a tuple of arrays; it's supposed to give you a single integer, an index into the flattened form of `RSS`. Are you sure your posted code and output are correct?

Comment: @user2357112 You are absolutely right, I've mixed different inputs and outputs. I've edited my question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest fix based on what you have right now would just be to extract the elements from the array as a final step:

```
# ij_min = (array([3]), array([20]))
ij_min = np.where(RSS == RSS_min)
ij_min = tuple([i.item() for i in ij_min])
```

Comment: I've tried. I get an error: 'ij_min = tuple([i.item() for i in ij_min])
NameError: name 'ij_min' is not defined. As I'm new to Python, I could have missing something, isn't it? Should I define ij_min somewhere? How?

Comment: That line of code is assuming you've already run the previous lines. I'll edit my response to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `argmin` with [`unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html).

For example, here's an array `RSS`:

```
In [123]: np.random.seed(123456)

In [124]: RSS = np.random.randint(0, 99, size=(5, 8))

In [125]: RSS
Out[125]: 
array([[65, 49, 56, 43, 43, 91, 32, 87],
       [36,  8, 74, 10, 12, 75, 20, 47],
       [50, 86, 34, 14, 70, 42, 66, 47],
       [68, 94, 45, 87, 84, 84, 45, 69],
       [87, 36, 75, 35, 93, 39, 16, 60]])
```

Use `argmin` (which returns an integer that is the index in the *flattened* array), and then pass that to `unravel_index` along with the shape of `RSS` to convert the index of the flattened array into the indices of the 2D array:

```
In [126]: ij_min = np.unravel_index(RSS.argmin(), RSS.shape)

In [127]: ij_min
Out[127]: (1, 1)
```

`ij_min` itself can be used as an index into `RSS` to get the minimum value:

```
In [128]: RSS_min = RSS[ij_min]

In [129]: RSS_min
Out[129]: 8
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me in multiple dimensions. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.rand((1000)).reshape(10,10,10)

print np.array(np.where(array == array.min())).flatten()
```

in the case of multiple minimums you could try something like

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1,1,2,3],[1,1,4,5]])

print zip(*np.where(array == array.min()))
```

Comment: Non at all. I obtain a looooong list of index, meaningless to me. Something like: [ 0  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9...

Comment: oh yea I guess it would break pretty hard if there are multiple min values ... I'll leave this here since someone upvoted it, if someone posts a better answer I'll remove this one.

Comment: @ariel67 can you update your question to specify what should happen in the case that the array has multiple min values?

Comment: @ John I'm not sure to understand your question. Do you mean "what should happen if in the matrix two elements have the same value, corresponding to the minimum value?". In that case, I would like to have the index of both elements, but given the nature of my data, this is a really unlikely situation.